# prevent git action from maintainers branch

Tags: github, github-actions

we have a repo with an github action for example:

```
name: our-deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main

jobs:
  build:  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
    steps:    
      - name: checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: setup environment
        run: echo "${{ secrets.SUPERSECRETENVVARIABLE }}"
      
      ...
```

we also have a branch protection rule: pushing directly on master is not allowed
at least, we do not want to give *(external)* maintainers the ability to push the code unproved to the cloud (function) or access our secrets

but one of the maintainers come to the clue to simply add his branchname to the push-on-branches array in his branch

```
name: our-deployment
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
      - maintainers-branch
```

*... and everything went live ...*

also, if he has bad intentions, he could find a way to read our secret credentials with one custom action

that leads me to my question:

**Is it possible and how could i prevent execution of actions from other than the default branch?**

Maybe something similar to "branch protection rules" alà "action protection rules"

Comment: Look at code owners - https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-on-github/about-code-owners

Comment: Another options is to adopt a pull request workflow: nobody gets to commit directly to the repository on any branch; all changes must come in via pull requests where they are reviewed before merging. This workflow would allow you to prevent exactly the situation you have described.

Comment: "branch protection" is an add-on feature, provided in this case by GitHub, not part of base Git; I snipped off the [tag:git] tag here.

Comment: you're right, ty @torek